# reshape2 dcast - values in fun.aggregate tabulate

Tags: r, reshape2

I would like to tabulate a long data.frame. The following example code creates a long data.frame, with columns "ID", "unit" and "mat". Using dcast I would like to create a wide format data.frame with new columns for each "mat", and the values should be either 1 (this combination exists) or 0 (nope, not there...).

```
df.long <- data.frame(ID = c(3, 4, 8, 9, 3, 4, 10, 3, 3, 4),
    unit = c("cm", "cm", "m", "K", "cm", "cm", "m", "cm", "m", "cm"),
    mat = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))
dcast(df.long, ID + unit ~ mat)
```

gives me a data frame looking the following way:

```
ID unit  1  2  3
1  3   cm  1  2  3
2  3    m NA NA  3
3  4   cm  1  2  3
4  8    m  1 NA NA
5  9    K  1 NA NA
6 10    m NA  2 NA
```

To get the table filles with 1 and 0 (as planned), the only way I find right now is adding an additional column to the long data.frame and use "fun.aggregate = tabulate" as additional dcast parameter, i.e.:

```
df.long <- data.frame(ID = c(3, 4, 8, 9, 3, 4, 10, 3, 3, 4),
    unit = c("cm", "cm", "m", "K", "cm", "cm", "m", "cm", "m", "cm"),
    mat = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    value = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
dcast(df.long, ID + unit ~ mat, fun.aggregate = tabulate)

ID unit 1 2 3
1  3   cm 1 1 1
2  3    m 0 0 1
3  4   cm 1 1 1
4  8    m 1 0 0
5  9    K 1 0 0
6 10    m 0 1 0
```

Despite it now works as intended, I wonder if anyone has a better approach using only dcast functionality, without altering the initial data.frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roland's approach definitely works, but it might make more sense to simply use `as.logical` for the aggregation function:

```
dcast(df.long, ID + unit ~ mat, 
      fill = 0, 
      fun.aggregate = as.logical, 
      value.var =  "mat")
#   ID unit 1 2 3
# 1  3   cm 1 1 1
# 2  3    m 0 0 1
# 3  4   cm 1 1 1
# 4  8    m 1 0 0
# 5  9    K 1 0 0
# 6 10    m 0 1 0
```

Try `as.logical(-1:3)` to get a sense of what gets converted to zero and what gets converted to one.

Comment: This might make sense for zero values in `df.long`, but from the description I assume those should be indicated as existent (i.e., `1`.)

Comment: Beside the identical outcome, this approach follows more logical my initial point of assigning some value (1) for "it exists" and (0) for nope, i.e. true false. However, both dcast solutions require the `fill = 0`statement, despite especially in the solution with `fun.aggregate = as.logical` I would expect this functionallity as intrinsic.

Comment: @PJussel The default option in fill is `NA `, which have to be changed

Answer (score 2):

I think this does the job:

```
dcast(df.long, ID + unit ~ mat, 
      fill = 0, 
      fun.aggregate = function(x) 1)
#  ID unit 1 2 3
#1  3   cm 1 1 1
#2  3    m 0 0 1
#3  4   cm 1 1 1
#4  8    m 1 0 0
#5  9    K 1 0 0
#6 10    m 0 1 0
```

Comment: Despite I do not fully understand the syntax of the fun.aggregate parameter, this solution works perfectly well! Thanks.

PS: Is the string "function(x) 1" a shortcut version of fun <- function(x) { 1 } ?

Comment: If your expression is only one line of code you don't need the curly braces. `fun.aggregate` expects a function. That can also be an anonymous function (defined on the fly).